No such file in directory?
I have folders. The CTK folder contains assets,view,login.py. In assets contains the images folder, in images contains photos. In view is not yet main.py. My question is why do I run the main file from login with the following error even though I have specified the correct file path?
file main.py
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))  # Di chuyển lên 1 thư mục để vào CTK
assets_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'assets', 'images')  # Thay đổi để đảm bảo đường dẫn đúng

# Hàm tải hình ảnh
def load_image(filename, size):
    image_path = os.path.join(assets_dir, filename)
    try:
        image = Image.open(image_path).resize(size)
        return CTkImage(image, size=size)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File not found: {image_path}")
        raise  # Tái phát sinh lỗi để dừng chương trình

file login.py
def show_main():
    try:
        # Kiểm tra xem app đã được khởi tạo hay chưa trước khi hủy
        if app:
            app.destroy()
        from View import main # Import tại đây có thể gây ra vấn đề vòng lặp import
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Lỗi trong show_main: {e}")

Here is error
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe C:\Users\admin\Documents\skype\CTK\login.py
Kết nối thành công đến cơ sở dữ liệu MySQL
[{'user_id': 14, 'username': 'bim', 'password_hash': '20d8c276b8e9801568963497d299f2501dc18f078ca95b4a555d8646e7af720c', 'email': 'bim@gmail.com', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 10, 1, 20, 23)}]
invalid command name "1374820852736update"
while executing
"1374820852736update"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1374820974400check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"1374820974400check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1374856334464_click_animation"
while executing
"1374856334464_click_animation"
("after" script)
Lỗi trong show_main: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../assets/images/search.png'


It does not make sense that base_dir would be ...  You need to figure out why that is.

Do you need os.path.dirname twice? I would suggest trying with the full path hard-coded and then work you way from there to see what is different

I understood why. When I read the main file from the login file, cwd (current working directory) is the directory that contains the login file. But why not convert cwd to the main file for easy management when reading the main file from another folder?
